# What is Ruby current class actually is?

Tags: ruby

In Metaprogramming Ruby, it told us that not only `self` but also a current class exists in the Ruby.

My question is: how to know what the current class is now? if we define a method, where the definition is put? What confuses me is the difference between these two codes. The running result is not the same.

It indicates that maybe when we want to define a method, we use `class` to open a class, and then define `self.method`, is not the same as using class `<< self` to open a class, and then define methods. Actually, it would not use in practical work, but I just want to know.

```
class C
  def self.m1
    puts "when in m1, self is #{self}"
    def m2; end
  end
end

class D < C
end

C.m1
  # when in m1, self is C
C.instance_methods false 
  #=> [:m2] 
C.methods false 
  #=> [:m1]
```

```
class C
  class << self
    def m1
      puts "when in m1, self is #{self}"
      def m2
      end
    end
  end
end

class D < C; end

C.m1
  # when in m1, self is C
C.instance_methods false 
  #=> [] 
C.methods false
  #=> [:m1, :m2]
```

Comment: the first result is: "when in m1, self is C" [m2] [m1]; the second result is: "when in m1, self is C"  []  [m1, m2]

Comment: [`Object#singleton_class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class).

Comment: https://blog.yugui.jp/entry/846

Comment: What is the point of defining the subclass `D`? A detail: by using awesome print in your code, readers (like me) who wish to run your code and do not use awesome print must edit the code before they can do so. There is no need to use that gem so please don't.

Comment: be careful with the use of your terminology - the current object is different to the current class

Answer (score 0):

The current class of first code snippet is `C`. Although you define `m2` in `self.m1`, the current class is `C`. `m2` is the instance method.

The current class of the second snippet is **singleton_class** of `C`. when you write `class << self`, you open a singleton class of the current class, `C` in this case. So the m2 is an instance method of **singleton_class** of `C`.